# Does my laptop need powerbank with output voltage the same like my charger's or my battery's?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, laptop

I have laptop (Acer Aspire 7745G) which has charger 19V-4.74A and battery 11.1V - 6,6Ah (73Wh). I'm planning to buy powerbank for it but I don't know what voltage would be okay. I'm looking to [this powerbank](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32813376074.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.72ec2b70OaZOB2&algo_pvid=81a5c81d-5021-49de-81d9-ea78eb62a449&algo_expid=81a5c81d-5021-49de-81d9-ea78eb62a449-9&btsid=eb57c54a-92c0-4075-8d10-966162bb835a&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3,searchweb201603_55) I see that it has DC output of 12/15/19V. So, can I use this powerbank for my laptop? If yes, what voltage of output should I use?

Comment: I want to use it as replacement of battery because there are no battery for my laptop which has more than 100Wh.

Comment: Laptop internal charging and power supply circuitry will PROBABLY require voltage about the same as the charger, NOT the bttery.

Comment: @RussellMc Thanks, I thought the same just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly will **not** be able to replace a specific laptop's battery with a "power bank". The motherboard will not recognize the power bank as a valid battery, so it will not attempt to charge it. There is a communications protocol between the motherboard and the battery, and the exact nature of the messages is usually not public.

Comment: But if I have battery removed and maintaining with powerbank which is connected to DC port, so, computer will work, yes? And if I put battery back to laptop it will not charge, right? Even if it will not charge battery, is it dangerous to have it inserted while maintaining with powerbank? In your answer "so it will not attempt to charge it" do you mean charging laptop or battery?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say. What "DC port" are you talking about? How can the battery be "inserted while maintaining with powerbank"? I can't figure out what is being connected to the powerbank and what is being connected to the battery.

Comment: By saying "DC port" I mean laptop charging port. Maybe It's called AC, ain't sure.

Comment: By saying "inserted while maintaining with powerbank" I mean, while original battery is in its slot, using external powerbank which is charged and turned on and connected to laptop's charging port.